# Alternatives to using Apps Script because of the 30 mins max run time

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps, cloud

Hi I'm doing a task which takes around 10 hours.

**Task**: Call an API 100,000 times for 100,000 inputs and store results in a google spreadsheet.

Since apps script has a time limit of 30 mins, I have to do it in many batches. I don't want to do it in batches as it needs manual intervention in between. Also, I have looked into options of creating triggers and didn't find it that convenient.

Any other easy/convenient/efficient alternatives to AppsScript which don't have such a short time limit?

I have access to GCP and would be ok with alternatives related to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of using Google Sheet use a serious database.
2. Instead of using AppScript write a Python script that query that API.